# How to get data transfer completion status in nifi for SFTP transfer

Tags: rest, apache-nifi, nifi-api

I have created a flow in nifi to transfer data from one linux machine to another linux machine.

Flow is like this:

*GetSFTP-->UpdateAttribute-->PutSFTP*

Everything I am managing through nifi APIs, i.e. creating, updating attributes and starting of flow using nifi APIs.

How can I get the completion status of data transfer, so that I can stop the flow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of being "complete" is something that NiFi can't really know here. How would NiFi know that another file isn't going to be added to the directory where GetSFTP is watching?

From NiFi's perspective the dataflow is running until someone says to stop it. It is not really meant to be a job system where you submit a job that starts and completes, it is a running dataflow that handles an infinite stream of data.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but what if I know the size at source side(i.e. it is fixed, let's say 500Gb)...is there any property of PutSFTP which I can use to compare the sizes at source and destination?